# gae jdoquery parameters with special characters

Tags: google-app-engine, parameters, special-characters, jdo

I am writing a cloud endpoint api using JDO to fetch a list of users based on the emailid. I am passing emailId as a @Named parameter to the Api method and adding it to the query filter and i get the error message "Portion of expression could not be parsed: @gmail.com"

```
@Api (name="MyAppname", version="v1")
public class PersonEndpoint {

public Person validate(@Named("emailId") String emailId, @Named("role") String role){
.......

PersistenceManager pm=getPersistenceManager();
Query q = pm.newQuery(Person.class);
q.setFilter(" email == "+emailId+" && role == "+role);

try{
    person=(Person)q.execute();
}finally{
    q.closeAll();
    pm.close();
}

return person;
}
```

When i call the above api, the below error is thrown

```
javax.jdo.JDOUserException: Portion of expression could not be parsed: @gmail.com && role == collector
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:519)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.execute(JDOQuery.java:230)
```

How do we pass parameters with special characters as in email to the query filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not embed text strings in a text string. Instead you define a **parameter**, and provide the parameter value to `execute()`.

```
Query q = pm.newQuery(Person.class);
q.setFilter("emailId == :theEmail && role == :theRole");
Map<String, String> paramValues = new HashMap();
paramValues.put("theEmail", myEmailParam);
paramValues.put("theRole", myRoleParam);
List<Person> persons = (List<Person>)q.executeWithMap(paramValues);
```

All of this is defined with examples in the JDO spec, and in [the docs for DataNucleus JDO](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_2/jdo/jdoql.html). I'd strongly suggest you read them

Comment: Thanks for ur help! But making those changes did not work. I get the error "javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: Unexpected expression type while parsing query. Variables not supported by GAE (email)"

Comment: There is no variable in that statement if email and role are fields in the Person class. Fact. If you really mean to say your field in Person (class not published) is emailId then put emailId. Anyone reading such a question cannot be expected to be psychic

Comment: Yes 'emailId' and 'role' are the fields in Person class as strings. `public Person validate(@Named("emailId") String emailId,@Named("role") String role,@Named("pwd") String pwd){
  Person person=new Person();
  
  PersistenceManager pm=getPersistenceManager();
  Query q = pm.newQuery(Person.class);
  
  q.setFilter("email == :emailIdParam && role == :roleParam");
  Map<String, String> paramValues = new HashMap();
  paramValues.put("emailIdParam", emailId);
  paramValues.put("roleParam", role);
  List<Person> persons = (List<Person>)q.executeWithMap(paramValues);`

Comment: no idea what you're trying there. Change the field names in the query, not the parameter names! See my answer.

Comment: Oops! Had made a silly mistake ; the field name in the datastore was emailId and i was going on trying with email :P Thanks!